# Mod Rewrite from Uppercase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a URL of www.somesite.com/BEARS to www.somesite.com/bears.  I'm having an issue in that I don't want all my URLs lowercase right now so I just want to do it on this one.

Also www.somesite.com/bears is actually rewriting to bears.php?page=bears.

I just can't think of a way to do this correctly.

I've tried

```
RewriteRule ^/BEARS$ /bears [PT]
RewriteRule ^/BEARS$ /bears.php?page=bears
```

That doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out here is my solution.

```
RewriteRule ^BEARS bears.php?page=bears [NC,L]
```

Apparently the forward slash was throwing me off